# How to store values from foreach loop into an array?

Tags: php, foreach

Need to store values from foreach loop into an array, need help doing that.

The code below does not work, only stores the last value, tried `$items .= ...,` but that is not doing the trick either, any help will be appreciated.

```php
foreach($group_membership as $i => $username) {
    $items = array($username);
}

print_r($items);
```

Comment: `.=` appends text. `[]` appends onto an array.

Comment: By far Skilldrick nailed it with the one liner above no need to go any further.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Declare the `$items` array outside the loop and use `$items[]` to add items to the array:

```
$items = array();
foreach($group_membership as $username) {
 $items[] = $username;
}

print_r($items);
```

Comment: Also, don't extract the key (`$i`) if you're not going to use it.

Comment: what would happen if some of the $username are null?  We have a similar situation where records are coming form an API, and somehow we are ending up with some null records in the array.

Answer (score 16):

Use

```
$items[] = $username;
```

Comment: Just make sure `$items = array();` appears before the loop.

Comment: Can you help explain why you have to declare $items = array(); before the loop.  I did something like this and didn't declare it and it still works.  Is it better to add it or is it not required?

Comment: Check this out @robk27 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246047/is-it-necessary-to-declare-php-array-before-adding-values-with

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php 
$items = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($group_membership as $i => $username) { 
 $items[$count++] = $username; 
} 
print_r($items); 
?>
```

Comment: No need for $count stuff. Just $array[] = $thing;

Comment: I am going to hold off on downvoting this answer although: 1. It is a code-only answer that 2.Teaches developers unnecessary/bad practices ...because this is a great chance to do the Disciplined thing and make Stackoverflow a better resource.

Comment: I have issue where my array returns only last element that was pushed into array. Using count as suggested by you resolved my issue.

Comment: Great answer for having different values with same name in associative arrays. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
$items = array_values ( $group_membership );
```

Comment: Well I assume the foreach loop is doing more than that, otherwise this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do my answer,

you wrote this:

```
<?php
foreach($group_membership as $i => $username) {
    $items = array($username);
}

print_r($items);
?>
```

And in your case I would do this:

```
<?php
$items = array();
foreach ($group_membership as $username) { // If you need the pointer (but I don't think) you have to add '$i => ' before $username
    $items[] = $username;
} ?>
```

As you show in your question it seems that you need an array of usernames that are in a particular group :) In this case I prefer a good sql query with a simple while loop ;)

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT `username` FROM group_membership AS gm LEFT JOIN users AS u ON gm.`idUser` = u.`idUser`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { \
    $items[] = $username; 
} 
?>
```

`while` is faster, but the last example is only a result of an observation. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it:

```
foreach($orders as $item){
   $transactionIds[]  =   $item->generated_order_id;
}

dump($transactionIds);
```

This is assuming $orders collection has a field called 'generated_order_id'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items=array(); 
$j=0; 

foreach($group_membership as $i => $username){ 
    $items[$j++]=$username; 
}
```

Just try the above in your code .

Comment: This code-only answer should not be used by any developers.  The counter and incrementing are not necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just to save you too much typos:

```
foreach($group_membership as $username){
        $username->items = array(additional array to add);
    }
    print_r($group_membership);
```

Answer (score -1):

this question seem quite old but incase you come pass it, you can use the PHP inbuilt function array_push() to push data in an array using the example below.

```
<?php
    $item = array();
    foreach($group_membership as $i => $username) {
        array_push($item, $username);
    }
    print_r($items);
?>
```

Comment: Making iterated function calls is inefficient.  The square brace pushing syntax (suggested 8 years earlier) will be more efficient.  This answer should not be used to push single elements into an array. (and the declaration of `$i` is useless)