# Is it necessary or useful to initialize sub-arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have a variable which is an initialized, empty array.

```
$cache = [];
```

The data in this array can be created like this, for example (please excuse the crude code and variable/key names, they're here for the sake of this example only):

```
for ($row in $someOtherArray) {
    $cache[$row['id']][] = $row['data'];
}
```

Since `$cache` is a PHP array, I don't really need to initialize `$cache[$row['id']]` to also be an array. However, I sometimes encounter code like this:

```
for ($row in $someOtherArray) {
    if (!isset($cache[$row['id']])) {
        $cache[$row['id']] = [];
    }

    $cache[$row['id']][] = $row['data'];
}
```

Above, the sub-array is explicitly initialized as an empty array. Is it useful somehow? For example - does it help the interpreter in some way? Or is it only a developer being overzealous?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to declare PHP array before adding values with \[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246047/is-it-necessary-to-declare-php-array-before-adding-values-with)

Comment: @Tschallacka, I don't think it's a duplicate, as the two questions are not exactly the same thing. Because the answers are not the same, they are practically the opposite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unnecessary as far as PHP is concerned. PHP will implicitly create any number of sub-arrays for you using the `$foo[$bar][]` syntax. It *may* be required for business logic, though not in this particular arrangement; it's simply redundant here. If the value assignment is somehow separate logic, but you still want to ensure that at least an empty array exists for the key, that's the only time it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have initialised a variable as an array, you can use array specific methods on that variable. For example array_push(), array_map() etc..