# Return only unique values from foreach

Tags: php, yii

I'm currently trying to use a foreach to return all the addresses using the relation from my event model. All is fine, returns all the addresses but will return even the duplicate results. I tried the array_unique but not sure I have the syntax correct.

```
<?php  
    foreach ($data->events as $address) {
        //array_unique($address, SORT_REGULAR);
        echo $address->getAddressString() ."<br/> <br/>";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Dont select duplicates in the 1st place - how are you querying the database

Comment: This is code I inherited, it's not got documentation and is fairly spaghetti like, I would happily change how the database is queried but due to time constraints at the minute it is important that I just get this working. 

It looks at the event model and goes through to the relations public function getAddressString() {
        return $this->venue->address->building_name . ', ' . $this->venue->address->street_name . ', ' . $this->venue->address->city . ', ' . $this->venue->address->post_code;
    }

I'm not sure how else the data is being pulled but I know the function is being used elsewhere

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should try with [array store technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045619/need-to-store-values-from-foreach-loop-into-array) using [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
//  First Store data in $arr
$arr = array();
foreach ($data->events as $address) {
    $arr[] = $address->getAddressString();
}
$unique_data = array_unique($arr);
// now use foreach loop on unique data
foreach($unique_data as $val) {
       echo $val;;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add each unique element to a new array and then see if they exist with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$uniques = [];
foreach($data->events as $address){
    if(!in_array($address->getAddressString(), $uniques)){
        $uniques[] = $address->getAddressString();
        echo $address->getAddressString()."<br><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `in_array` will get slower and slower as the array grows. Better to save the values as keys instead. No function calls are required and uniqueness is guaranteed. By the way if you need to check if a value exists in an array, `array_key_exists` is much faster than `in_array`. I always store unique values as keys rather than values if possible. Of course, the OP should try to get the data model to return only unique values in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`array_unique` should do it. Try this:

```
<?php  
foreach (array_unique($data->events) as $address) {
    echo $address->getAddressString() ."<br/> <br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Error : Object of class Event could not be converted to string.

I believe this what I tried first.

Answer (score 1):

There's a faster way, if you'd like to prematurely optimize.

```
<?php  
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($data->events as $address) {
        $arr[$address->getAddressString()] = 'a'; // value doesn't matter
        // using inherent uniqueness of keys.
    }
    // $addrs = array_keys($arr);
    // optionally, take all those array keys and put them in values.
    // keys would become regular numeric keys
  ?>
```

That should run faster than any of the other answers here. But it will only make a difference if you are dealing with large amounts of data.

If you want to echo, you will want to do `array_keys` if you didn't above. Here it is in one line:

```
echo implode(', ',array_keys($arr)); // comma separated list of unique values
```

Or this, for sorted:

```
$addrs = array_keys($arr);
sort($addrs);
echo implode(', ',$addrs); // sorted list
```

Finally, I'd like to add that you *should* be getting unique, ordered results from your data model in the first place. The database is much faster and better at simple tasks like ordering unique results than your PHP code ever will be.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `address` FROM `table`
WHERE `city` LIKE 'Lodi'
ORDER BY 'address' ASC
```

Comment: I won't be working with large amount of data for this particular instance, but this will no doubt come in handy when I'm exporting all of this at once..

Comment: Array keys in php are inherently unique and it's a fairly well known secret/shortcut to use the keys to store unique values rather than the values. Php also has functions like ksort, etc that apply directly to keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
<?php  
    $all_addresses= array();
    foreach ($data->events as $address) {
        $all_addresses[]= $address->getAddressString();
    }
    $all_addresses= array_unique($all_addresses);
    foreach($all_addresses as $val) {
       echo $val . "<br/> <br/>";
    }
?>
```

Or

Instead of

```
    foreach($all_addresses as $val) {
       echo $val . "<br/> <br/>";
    }
```

Do

```
    echo implode('<br/> <br/>', $all_addresses);
```

Comment: This answer did not return any results for me in the address. I'm not sure if it's my implementation as it looks similair to the working code submitted by Php developer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question was different I agree with Steve. You should adjust your query. Its faster, more readable and maintainable. You don't want to do anything you don't need to do.

If i gathered correctly you have to tables that are in relation. Great. Try something like this:

```
$var1 = YourModel::model()
->with('address_table')
->findAllByAttributes(array(-optional if you want certain columns-), 
                     array('condition'=>'`type` LIKE :type AND `typeId` = :typeId AND `suggestionId` IS NULL', 'params'=>array(':type'=>$_GET['type'], ':typeId'=>$_GET['typeId']), 'group'=>'address_table.`column`'));
```

Most important thing here for you is the 'group' command which like the name says groups results and returns only unique ones. Be sure to prefix it correctly, either table name or alias depending on what you are working with.
Hope it helps.