# getting duplicate values under nested loop in php

Tags: php, foreach, nested-loops

I want to use nested loop under 1 loop but i am getting duplicate results can somebody help ?

here is my code

```
 <ul>
                    <?php
                        $footer_category =  json_decode($this->db->get_where('general_settings',array('type' => 'footer_category'))->row()->value);
                        $categories = $this->db->get('category')->result_array();
                        foreach($categories as $row){
                        foreach($footer_category as $cat){
                    ?>
                    <li>                    
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <?php
                    print_r($cat);
                    //      echo $this->crud_model->get_type_name_by_id('category',$cat,'category_name');
                    ?>
                    </a>
                        <div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <?php
                                $subs = $this->db->get_where('sub_category',array('category'=>$row['category_id']))->result_array();
                                foreach($subs as $row1){
                                    $this->db->limit(4);
                                    $this->db->order_by('product_id','desc');
                                    $products = $this->db->get_where('product',array('sub_category'=>$row1['sub_category_id'],'status' =>'ok'))->result_array();
                            ?>
                                <div class="col-md-12"><h3 class="text-center" style="background:#EAEAEA;"><?php echo $row1['sub_category_name']; ?></h3></div>
                                <?php
                                    foreach($products as $row2){
                                        if($this->crud_model->is_publishable($row2['product_id'])){
                                ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="menu_box">
                                            <div class="img_menu_box" style="background:url('<?php echo $this->crud_model->file_view('product',$row2['product_id'],'','','no','src','multi','one') ?>') no-repeat center center; background-size: 100% auto;">
                                            </div>

                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->crud_model->product_link($row2['product_id']); ?>">
                                            <?php echo $row2['title']; ?>
                                        </a>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php 
                    }
                     ?>

                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>


                    </ul>
```

here are duplicate results of print_r($cat);

5
9
10
5
9
10
5
9
10
5
9
10
5
9
10
5
9
10
here are duplicate results in json print_r($footer_category);
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 )
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 )
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 )
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 )
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 )
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 )

> however expected results of print_r($cat); are 
>       5
>       9
>       10

i want to keep both loops for must because both loops has their own spot in code,

Comment: So then it seems like you don't need the outer loop, no?

Comment: need to keep outer loop as well because the outer loop has his own place after nested loop not share out loop code because it's too long, though might fill whole question page

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  If you don't want the list of footer categories to repeat for each item in `$categories`, then you shouldn't put it in that loop.

Comment: Post your JSON so we can replicate it...

Comment: @Edward Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 )

Comment: @PatrickQ i need to keep both loops

Comment: You can _keep_ them both, but based on the updated code, I see no reason for your `foreach($footer_category as $cat){` to be _inside_ your `foreach($categories as $row){`.  Anything you put inside there is going to happen each iteration of that loop.  If you don't want that, don't put it in there.  It's really that simple.

Comment: @PatrickQ can you please update & send code as answers, i will test test than

Comment: I can't give you an answer because you haven't shown what you expect your actual total output to be.  You keep saying that you need the `foreach($categories as $row){` loop, but you haven't shown how that relates to the footer categories.  I don't know if the footers should be before, after, or what.  Based on the information that you _have_ provided, all I can tell you is what I already have.

Comment: @PatrickQ in question I clearly target print_r($cat); from footer_category loop, i show whole code because someone ask me why i have first loop

Answer (score 0):

`print_r($cat);` is in

`foreach($footer_category as $cat){`
And this print what you expect

> 5 9 10

But this is in `foreach($categories as $row)`
 and this loop repeat `foreach($footer_category as $cat)` 6 times what give duplicated results.
If you move `foreach($footer_category as $cat){` from `foreach($categories as $row)` you receive expected results.

Comment: please send me code with changes i am not getting this

Comment: need to keep same position because it's an dynamic menu?

Comment: @JamezRoz I'm not sure what you want achieve. If you iterate on $categories and there trying create links from $footer category then $footer_category will be executed that many times how $categories has rows.

Comment: i think we need to do some tricky thing but i am not much experience with this stuff can you help me a bit with this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290643/return-only-unique-values-from-foreach