# How to fetch multiple data from database and store in one variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch multiple row and store in one variable.Here is my function for fetch data.

I want to fetch all row which type is service. and display all data in php.

**Get value function**

```
public function getvalue() {
    $db = connectionstart();
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE type='service' LIMIT 3");
    $result = mysql_evaluate($db, $sql);

    connectionclose($db);
    return $result;
}
```

**mysql_evaluate function**

```
function mysql_evaluate($db, $sql) {
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
        return $default_value;
    else
        return mysql_result($result, 0);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: how to use mysqli or pdo

Comment: I've also included the links in my comment. Click on them to read about these database extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your function as below:-

```
public function getvalue() {
    $db = connectionstart();
     // No need of bracket here
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE type='service' LIMIT 3";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    // declare an array
    $data = [];
    if($result){
        // loop
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                 // store data in an array
                 $data[] = $row; 

         }    
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try with [array store technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045619/need-to-store-values-from-foreach-loop-into-array)

```
//  First Store data in $data
$data = array();
$result = mysql_evaluate($db, $sql, $defaultvalue);
foreach ($result  as $row) {
    $data [] = $row;
}
// Your all data will be store in $data variable
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  give this typ of error @Php Developer

Comment: @KevinPPatel check this `print_r($result)` and let me know which kind array are you retrieving..

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) article on w3schools.com, especially the part with `$row=$result->fetch_assoc()`